# xcode / ios app distrubution ad hoc

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

Is it possible to distribute an app via ad-hoc without first putting the device into development mode?
I have successfully managed to download and install my app from a simple web page with the ipa and a manifest file, and I would like to test this on a friends device who is located elsewhere in the country.

Would he have to set his device in development mode for this to work, and if in that case, is there any way to easily do that without having xcode installed on his mac?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestFlight is your best friend for this. Export the ipa file and upload it to your account on [TestFlightApp.com](http://testflightApp.com) .  Then all you need are your user's UDID's and they'll be able to download your build directly from the testFlight app on their phone. No xcode or development mode required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your friend can install it, but only up to 100 devices. I'm almost positive he doesnt have to be in development mode. https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html is my source.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "yes".

You can install ADHOC builds onto any devices you have the device identifier (UDID) for.

There may be more nuances to this, but I believe the main purpose of a device being in "development mode" is so you can attach that device directly to your development machine, where you can step through line by line when debugging within Xcode, or be able to easily look at the Console or Crash logs on your connected device.